# When can a matrix $\Lambda\in SL(4,R)$ be represented by $SL(2,C)$?

Tags: matrices, lie-groups

I was just curious if anyone knows what kind of constraints one can place on $SL(4,R)$ the set of 4x4 invertible matrices with unit determinant to obtain: $SL(2,C)$ the set of 2x2 invertible complex matrices with unit determinant. I'm guessing that if one places a particular constaint on the former set then they are isomorphic to the latter?

Essentially I'm trying to show that a particular set of matrices I have might be represented in terms of $SL(2,C)$ rather than the current form I have them in $SL(4,R)$. Thanks a ton!

Comment: This would be easier to answer, I think, if you stated what the current form you have them in is

Comment: Are you aware of the usual way of representing $GL(n,\Bbb C)$ in $GL(2n,\Bbb R)$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom  No, I wasn't, but I think the below answer straightened me out! (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\Lambda$ is of the form:
$$\Lambda = \begin{bmatrix}
a&b&c&d \\
-b&a&-d&c \\
e&f&g&h \\
-f&e&-h&g
\end{bmatrix}$$
then we can isomorphically map it to:
\begin{bmatrix}
a+ib&c+id \\
e+if&g+ih
\end{bmatrix}

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I needed!! (:

Comment: In terms of Kronecker products (tensor products), we can write this association as 
$$
\pmatrix{a&c\\e&g} + i\pmatrix{b&d\\f&h} \leftrightarrow 
\pmatrix{a&c\\e&g}\otimes\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1} + \pmatrix{b&d\\f&h}\otimes \pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0}
$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom   Thank you, that also actually helps quite a bit. Sorry physicist here trying to learn groups (: